# Does anyone know where USG has made the hardening configuration of the USB storage and how to reverse the hardening?

Tags: server, usb-drive

Genuine question.

The server has a stock install of the Ubuntu Server 20.04 with the USG cis_level1_server script executed. Right now, I would like to re-enable the USB storage. How can I do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhardening/enabling USB storage after running USG cis\_level1\_server on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1472150/unhardening-enabling-usb-storage-after-running-usg-cis-level1-server-on-ubuntu-2)